# Convergence Proof Help?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

**Question:**

> Let ($x_n$) and ($y_n$) be given, and define ($z_n$) to be the "shuffled" sequence $(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, x_3, y_3,...x_n, y_n)$. Prove that $(z_n)$ is convergent if and only if $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are both convergent with $\lim x_n = \lim y_n$.

I know I need to prove both direction of the implication.

The first direction being if $(z_n)$ is convergent then so are $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ with $\lim x_n=\lim y_n$. I said let $(z_n)\rightarrow c$.

So since ($z_n$) converges, I know that given any positive $\varepsilon$, there exists N such that if $$n\geq N, z_n \in (c-\varepsilon, c+\varepsilon) \implies  |x_n |<|c|+\varepsilon$$ for all $n\geq N$.

I'm stuck at the next step in seeing how this leads to proving that $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ converge. I'm inclined to say something like:

Since the elements of $(x_n)$ are also elements of $(z_n)$, then there exists $N_1$$\in$$\mathbb{N}$ such that $$n\geq N_1 \implies  x_n \in(c-\varepsilon, c+\varepsilon)$$

And from there I'm stuck. Any helpful hints on what direction to go would be appreciated!

Comment: Then as $y_n$ converges, there exists a $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If a sequence converges to some limit, then so do all of its subsequences, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A subsequence of a convergent sequence is convergent.

Conversely, setting $z_{2n - 1} = x_n $ and $z_{2n} = y_n$. As $\lim x_n = \lim y_n = a$, for any given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb N $ such that

$$n > n_1 \implies |x_n - a| < \varepsilon \\  n > n_2 \implies |x_n - a| < \varepsilon$$

Consider $n_0 = \max \{2n_1 - 1, 2n_2\}$.

Comment: Then for all n$>$$n_o$, $\mid$$z_n$-a$\mid$$<$$\epsilon$, so $z_n$ converges to a ?

Comment: That's correct.